# Customise Outlook Address Book using c#

Tags: outlook

How to add button ,image,textbox in  Outlook Address Book using C# Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Address Book window is not customizable.

Comment: You can't. At least there is no officially supported way of doing that.